# Calling method of another class on Onclick of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, I have got an weather app, My `WeatherFragment` class got below code, which is of a fragment class.

```
btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Change city");
            final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            builder.setView(input);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
                  obj.changeCityLocation(input.getText().toString());
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

and I need to call `changeCityLocation()` which is in `MainActivity`, which code is:

```
public void changeCityLocation(String city){
    WeatherFragment wf = (WeatherFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    wf.changeCity(city);
    new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
}
```

I need to take the input and store in city variable when I click ok but it crashed. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `MainActivity` is Activity or normal java class ?

Comment: seems this guy is making an instance of the host activity

Comment: make changeCityLocation is static function and call with direct class name without creating object

Comment: Thankyou all sirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong here

```
MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
```

Because this is not possible. All Activities in android must go through the Activity lifecycle so that they have a valid context attached to activity. so you have to use getActivity() method to get parent activity object and then cast it to MainActivity. like this

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeCityLocation(input.getText().toString());
```

This will allow you to access Parent activity methods from fragment.

Comment: Thankyou So much sir, I am new to Android and I only know basic java, So I getting errors, Dear Sir it would be nice if u give me a hint from Where can i learn Proper Android Development and Java too. Thankyou Sir.

Comment: @BikeshPawn Just Google it and you will find thousands of tutorial for development. even you can read official document also.